# woocommerce get shipping cost from zone id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am working in woocommerce add order from API. I already added order by using `wc_create_order()` function. In that, I have added shipping address, billing address, and product details as well. But the problem is I want to add shpping cost as per shipping zone.

Here is screenshot :

[image]

However I found class with function called : `WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones().`

But it return unarranged (unmanaged) array.
 I have **state code** and then I want to get shipping cost from state code.

However, I have found **zone_id**.
 I have already tried to use `WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by('zone_id',$zone_id),WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone($zone_id);`

But none of functions return ***cost*** anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to get the zone cost. I hope it helps.

global $post, $woocommerce;

```
$delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
foreach ((array) $delivery_zones as $key => $the_zone ) {
  echo $the_zone['zone_name'];
  echo "<br/>";
  foreach ($the_zone['shipping_methods'] as $value) {
    echo $value->cost;
  }
  echo "<br/>";
}
```